# How can i display Time and date in only hours and minutes

Tags: c#, datetime

I wanna show the current date and hours and minutes like this `14-11-2016 10:25`
but my code shows `14-11-2016 00:00`

my Code

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Today;
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
MessageBox.Show(date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));
```

Comment: Your `date` variable is a `Date` object and has no time on it this is why you are getting 00:00. Use a `DateTime` object instead like `var date = DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. Try this:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show(date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));
```

Using

```
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

you say you are only interested in the data part so it will remove the time part.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `dateAndTime.Date`, you're just getting the `Date` of the full object. The hours and minutes are set to `00:00`.

Try it like this:

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show(dateAndTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
DateTime.Now;
```

instead of

```
DateTime.Today;
```

and thus

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show(dateAndTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. As Mohit wrote you need to use `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Today`.

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
var time  = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```